# Vectorize scipy.stats.norm.logpdf

Tags: numpy, scipy

I am tryint to trying to train a Bayesian NN and at some point I need to compute log-likelihoods for some data points, according to a multivariate diagonal gaussian distribution with parameters (mu, sigma).
I have 2 problems:

1. I don't know the size of the values in advance (note that I am guaranteed that 'values', 'mu' and 'rho') are the same size, but they could either be 1D or 2D, which forces me to have an ugly `if` statement. Ideally I would just iterate over the elements no matter the size of the tensor.
2. This is painfully slow. I don't see how I could vectorize the logpdf the `numpy` way, as passing in the values, mu and sigma directly to norm.logpdf seems to implicitely construct a covariance matrix (which is too big and makes the program crash).

   ```
    from scipy.stats import norm

    ...

    mu    = self.mu.detach().numpy()
    sigma = np.log(1 + np.exp(self.rho.detach().numpy()))
    vals  = values.detach().numpy()
    log_likelihood_val = 0
    if len(values.size()) == 2:
        for i in range(values.size()[0]):
            for j in range(values.size()[1]):
                log_likelihood_val += norm.logpdf(vals[i,j], loc=mu[i,j], scale=sigma[i,j])
    else:
        for i in range(values.size()[0]):
            log_likelihood_val += norm.logpdf(vals[i], loc=mu[i], scale=sigma[i])
    return torch.tensor(log_likelihood_val)
   ```

How  should I implement it instead?

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up defining my own logpdf function so that it is easily vectorized, which solved both problems at once:

```
def log_likelihood(self, values: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    def logpdf(x, mu, sigma):
        return -(((x - mu)/sigma)**2)/2 - torch.log(np.sqrt(2*np.pi) * sigma)
        
    sigma = torch.log(1 + torch.exp(self.rho))
    log_likelihood_val = torch.sum(logpdf(values, self.mu, sigma))
    return log_likelihood_val
```

Hope this might help someone.

Comment: torch.log1p(torch.exp(self.rho)) might be a liiittle bit faster and better behaved if rho is negative

Comment: Thank you, I will use this instead!